# Hide & Reveal side toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I need some help with this project. I'm trying to get a picture as a background on a div element, that could be expanded and hid when clicked on. I don't know how to make the image a background for the div element, and I don't know how to make the div toggle from left to right.

I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="couch">Info about this couch</div>
    </body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"      charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\CSS\HTMLBook/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </html>
```

```css
#couch {
    height: 95px;
    width: 65px;
    background-color: silver;
    border: solid;
    top: 40%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px; 
    background-image: url("http://www.rowefurniture.com/uploads/images/sofas/thumb/C570.jpg");
}
```

Comment: FYI your HTML is invalid as `script` tags should be inside the `head` or `body`.

Comment: I made a Fiddle and, but do not understand your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Ss86Q/ What are you trying to do? On click, the div should expand to the size of the image?

Comment: Change your path for `app.js` to something more viable like `src="../HTMLBook/app.js"` and make sure you have regular slashes not backslashes. And why you put it in a folder named CSS is quite incomprehensible

Answer (score 0):

try this

html

```
<body>
    <div id="couch" class="collapseRemoved">Info about this couch</div>
</body>
```

css

```
    #couch {
   background-color: silver;
    border: solid;
    top: 40%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px; 
    background: url("http://www.rowefurniture.com/uploads/images/sofas/thumb/C570.jpg") 100% 100%;
    background-size:100%

}
.collapseRemoved{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;

}
.collapse{
    width:100px;
}
```

js code

```
 $("#couch").click(function(){    
    if($(this).hasClass("collapse")){
        $(this).removeClass("collapse").addClass("collapseRemoved");
    }else{

        $(this).removeClass("collapseRemoved").addClass("collapse");
    }   
});
```

Comment: THat's kinda the track I'm looking for. How would collapse the div by clicking on the picture? Thank you Rakesh! :)

Comment: Hi Alan, Try the above edited code. I hope this will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your page

```
<script>
$( "#couch" ).click(function() {
      $( "#couch" ).toggle(1000);
    });
</script>
```

test : http://jsfiddle.net/Ss86Q/1/

Comment: Inside the click method, you can use $(this) instead of $("#couch") because if you have multiple ids then it will consider always the first one.

Comment: This one seems to keep hide. How would make it so that it expands.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through your code and formatted it while also setting up a jfiddle. I hope this works and if not hopefully its a starting point. Please check my JSfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmcH8

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
$("#couch").toggle('slow');
 });
});
```

Comment: This is kinda what I'm looking for. Just without the button. How would you do that same event but just by clicking the picture? I tried removing the "button" section, but it doesn't work. THank you. :)

Comment: I've updated fiddle. Please let me know if this is what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nukiy/1/edit)

At first, the CSS

```
#couch {
    height: 95px;
    border: solid;
    top: 40%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px; 
    background-image: url("http://www.rowefurniture.com/uploads/images/sofas/thumb/C570.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Now Jquery:

1. If you want to change the width:

   $("#couch").click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("big");
   });

Add this to your css:

```
.big {
  width: 400px !important;
}
```

1. If you want to hide the div itself

   $("#couch").click(function() {
           $(this).toggle();
       });

In this example, if you toggle the div is hidden. How you want to restore it back.

I guess you are looking to collapse the div and expand it again.

In that case, change the height of the div based on click.

Hope its useful to you :)
Please try inserting the scripts inside the `<head></head>` tag

Comment: Still can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. It just collapses and disappears when I do it.